# Simplifying an equation over the domain of natural numbers

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

How can an equation like this be simplified in Mathematica where `q`,`a`,`b`,`k` are all natural numbers?

```
q = ((a*(b - 1))/ k) + (k - (Mod[(a*(b - 1)), k]))*(1/k)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with `FullSimplify`:

```
q = ((a*(b - 1))/ k) + (k - (Mod[(a*(b - 1)), k]))*(1/k);

FullSimplify[q]

(*1 + Floor[(a (-1 + b))/k]*)
```

**Edit**: thanks to the comments by @kirma and @Syed, here are the assumptions:

```
FullSimplify[q, (a | b | k) \[Element] PositiveIntegers]

(*1 + Floor[(a (-1 + b))/k]*)
```

Comment: This is simplification doesn't make domain assumptions on variables. It does produce the same result, but to exactly make the assumption that $a$, $b$ and $k$ are natural numbers (that is, non-zero integers) is to do something like `FullSimplify[q, a != 0 && b != 0 && k != 0 && (a | b | k) \[Element] Integers]`.

Comment: @kirma Can we use `PositiveIntegers`?

Comment: @Syed *cough cough* ... one shouldn't write comments right after waking up, especially on sick leave. I wonder where my "natural numbers are all integers except zero" idea came from.

There's some ambiguity regarding inclusion of zero on natural numbers, but I guess `PositiveIntegers` is the most common interpretation.

Comment: Thanks, @Syed! :-)

Comment: Thanks, @kirma! :-)

Comment: You are most welcome. @E.Chan-López